# SQLAlchemy, Psycopg2 and Postgresql COPY

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

It looks like Psycopg has a custom command for executing a [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

[psycopg2 COPY using cursor.copy_from() freezes with large inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491864/)

Is there a way to access this functionality from with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[It doesn't look like it](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/vZIztYaqlpo).

You may have to just use psycopg2 to expose this functionality and forego the ORM capabilities. I guess I don't really see the benefit of ORM in such an operation anyway since it's a straight bulk insert and dealing with individual objects a la an ORM would not really make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: super - can get to psycopg via engine.raw_connection()

Answer (score 41):

accepted answer is correct but if you want more than just the EoghanM's comment to go on the following worked for me in COPYing a table out to CSV...

```
from sqlalchemy import sessionmaker, create_engine

eng = create_engine("postgresql://user:pwd@host:5432/db")
ses = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

dbcopy_f = open('/tmp/some_table_copy.csv','wb')

copy_sql = 'COPY some_table TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER'

fake_conn = eng.raw_connection()
fake_cur = fake_conn.cursor()
fake_cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, dbcopy_f)
```

The `sessionmaker` isn't necessary but if you're in the habit of creating the engine and the session at the same time to use `raw_connection` you'll need separate them (unless there is some way to access the engine through the session object that I don't know). The sql string provided to `copy_expert` is also not the only way to it, there is a basic `copy_to` function that you can use with subset of the parameters that you could past to a normal `COPY` TO query. Overall performance of the command seems fast for me, copying out a table of ~20000 rows.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection

Comment: This was an awesome find. This reduced my time saving data from 8 hours+ overnight to just 4 minutes or so. Oh my!

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to do `fake_conn.commit()` at the end

Answer (score 31):

If your engine is configured with a psycopg2 connection string (which is the default, so either `"postgresql://..."` or `"postgresql+psycopg2://..."`), you can create a psycopg2 cursor from an SQL Alchemy session using

```
cursor = session.connection().connection.cursor()
```

which you can use to execute

```
cursor.copy_from(...)
```

The cursor will be active in the same transaction  as your session currently is. If a `commit` or `rollback` happens, any further use of the cursor with throw a `psycopg2.InterfaceError`, you would have to create a new one.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the asyncpg dialect? The driver itself has a `connection.copy_from_table` method but that is not available on the cursor. If I get a raw connection as in the other answers it won't be in the same transaction.

Answer (score 17):

You can use:

```
def to_sql(engine, df, table, if_exists='fail', sep='\t', encoding='utf8'):
    # Create Table
    df[:0].to_sql(table, engine, if_exists=if_exists)

    # Prepare data
    output = cStringIO.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(output, sep=sep, header=False, encoding=encoding)
    output.seek(0)

    # Insert data
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.copy_from(output, table, sep=sep, null='')
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

I insert 200000 lines in 5 seconds instead of 4 minutes

Comment: Could you give some details on what the `df` object is?

Comment: df is a pandas dataframe

Comment: This is gold! (using pandas and sqlalchemy and postgres)

Comment: I know its been a while, but could you explain why you are using pandas to_sql AND sqlalchemy copy_from? Doesn't to_sql create the table AND write the contents of df to the table? if so, why then insert the data after again? I'm using this to bulk insert data, but the destination table has a serial id as it's index, and which ever way I try I cant seem to be able to just insert the data without an index (without getting an error saying there's missing column data)

Comment: @JustinMoser As it happens, `pandas.DataFrame` has a [`to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html?highlight=sql) method, but that method is not used here. Instead, the [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method is used to store `df` in an [in-memory text stream](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o), `output`, which is then passed to `psycopg2` using [`raw_connection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection).

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk I realised shortly after leaving that comment that the first line usage of to_sql just writes the headers to the destination table. Is that correct?

Comment: @JustinMoser Oh, I completely missed that line! Yes, that line will `CREATE TABLE ...` with appropriate columns (or fail if the table already exists), but not insert any data.

Comment: that first line is smart .. the rest looks the same as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984180/4126114)

Comment: Is there anyway to simply create the SQLAlchemy model instead of the table (I love your code for creating the initial table with no data). I am trying to use Alembic and would like to create a best-guess model which I can then edit.

Answer (score 6):

If you're starting from SQLAlchemy, you need to first get to the connection engine (also known by the property name `bind` on some SQLAlchemy objects):

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:password@localhost/mydb')
# or 
engine = session.engine
# or any other way you know to get to the engine
```

From the engine you can isolate a psycopg2 connection:

```
# get a psycopg2 connection
connection = engine.connect().connection

# get a cursor on that connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Here are some templates for the COPY statement to use with `cursor.copy_expert()`, a more complete and flexible option than `copy_from()` or `copy_to()` as it is indicated here: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert.

```
# to dump to a file
dump_to = """
COPY mytable 
TO STDOUT
WITH (
    FORMAT CSV,
    DELIMITER ',',
    HEADER
);
"""

# to copy from a file:
copy_from = """
COPY mytable 
FROM STDIN
WITH (
    FORMAT CSV,
    DELIMITER ',',
    HEADER
);
"""
```

Check out what the options above mean and others that may be of interest to your specific situation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html.

IMPORTANT NOTE: The link to the documentation of `cursor.copy_expert()` indicates to use STDOUT to write out to a file and STDIN to copy from a file. But if you look at the syntax on the PostgreSQL manual, you'll notice that you can also specify the file to write to or from directly in the COPY statement. Don't do that, you're likely just wasting your time if you're not running as root (who runs Python as root during development?) Just do what's indicated in the psycopg2's docs and specify STDIN or STDOUT in your statement with `cursor.copy_expert()`, it should be fine.

```
# running the copy statement
with open('/path/to/your/data/file.csv') as f:
     cursor.copy_expert(copy_from, file=f)

# don't forget to commit the changes.
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to drop down to psycopg2, use raw_connection nor a cursor.

Just execute the sql as usual, you can even use bind parameters with [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text):

```
engine.execute(text('''copy some_table from :csv
                       delimiter ',' csv'''
                   ).execution_options(autocommit=True),
               csv='/tmp/a.csv')
```

You can drop the `execution_options(autocommit=True)` if [this PR](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/pull-requests/68/) will be accepted

Comment: Just disclose that it is your repository of code, which it appears to be

Comment: No, the one linked as "this PR" is not my repository, it's the normal/official repository for sqlalchemy. OTOH the PR is obviously mine, that's not a secret: I use the same username on both stackoverflow and bitbucket. Anyhow, I stumbled upon this question while researching examples for that change, and everything I've written is factually correct. I could've avoided linking the PR, but (in case it'll be accepted) then this answer will suggest an outdated snippet, unless me or someone will remember to update it after the fact

Comment: Adding a note to an old answer, but COPY naming a file requires database superuser privileges, which might not be very desirable.