# Getting raw psycopg2 cursor object from a SQLAlchemy session object

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am creating a session object using this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

maiden_engine = create_engine(connection_url)
session = sessionmaker(maiden_engine)
connector = session()
```

Now for a certain use case, I want to get `pyscopg2` `cursor` object from this `connector` object, is there a way this conversion can be achieved?

This is how you normally create a cursor object

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host, port, database, user, password, sslmode)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

> Note that this conversaion **HAS** to be made from `connector` object in the last line of first code snippet, I can not use `maiden_engine` or anything else.

Comment: Perhaps `crsr = connector.bind.raw_connection().cursor()` …?

Comment: hi @GordThompson hi thanks, it works! Can you please post it in an answer with how you reached this solution so I can accept it? Also if u think the question is worthy, pls upvote for others to find it easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the `connector` variable is a `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>` object. `Session` objects have a `.bind` attribute which returns the `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>` that is associated with the session.

`Engine` objects have a `.raw_connection()` method that returns (a proxy to) the raw DBAPI connection, and calling `.cursor()` on that returns a raw DBAPI `Cursor` object. Hence,

```py
crsr = connector.bind.raw_connection().cursor()
```

Comment: Using a `scoped_session`, not sure why but I had better luck using `crsr = session.connection().connection.cursor()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24267777/4653485).